# How to "migrate" actions, brushes, plugins etc from two Photoshop installation?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

On a PC i've installed both Photoshop CC 2017 and 2020.
I want to migrate all 2017 plugin, brushes, actions etc to 2020.

Do you know how ?

Thanks

Comment: [This helpx article](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/preset-migration.html) should have all the info you need.

Answer (score 1):

From [Adobe](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/preset-migration.html):

"By default, when you update to the latest version of Photoshop using the Creative Cloud desktop app, your presets, settings, and preferences are migrated from the earlier version of Photoshop. Also, when you launch Photoshop for the first time, you're prompted to migrate all available presets from the most recent version of Photoshop installed on your computer.

Presets can be migrated from the latest version installed before Photoshop, going back to Photoshop CS3.
...If you chose not to migrate your presets when you updated Photoshop, or if you faced issues while migrating presets, you can select Edit > Presets > Migrate Presets to migrate presets, settings, and preferences later in Photoshop. Photoshop looks for an older version of Photoshop on the same system and prompts you to migrate presets."

See link above or here for descriptions and instructions:
[Migrate presets, actions, and settings](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/preset-migration.html)